# .NET Core, Parallel Run of the same application with different configuration possible?

Tags: .net-core, configuration-files

I am trying to get my head around the .netcore way of configuring an application.

**Szenario**:

I am running the same rest api (application) for client1 and client2 on the same server in the DEV-Environment.
We have environment specific configurations as well as client specific configurations.

**"Old" Way:**

With web.config transformations, I created build configurations for dev-client1 and dev-client2 and set the values accordingly...this all worked fine.

**"New" Way:**

As the appsettings.json depends on the windows environment variable (one per server) and therefore run into troubles. I could not find a way so far to run the apps in parallel on the same server with different configurations.

I might have missunderstood the new way of configuring an application, therefore any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a typical new .NET Core web app, you will see this code in the Startup.cs:

```
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
```

all you need to do is add another appsettings file with client-specific settings, like:

```
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.client.json", optional: true)
```

then have your build script copy in the correct build configuration to `appsettings.client.json`. the `ConfigurationBuilder` will pick up the settings in all the sources and compile them into the `configuration` object.

also check out the full docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

Comment: Thanks for the reply dave. I am aware of the microsoft documentation and the configuration builder part. If I understand you correctly, the build script decides then for the correct file to pick. E.g. my build server sorts out the handling of client file now...if this is the only way to go, why would I bother about the appsettings.environment at all? I just think the environment variable takes away a lot of flexibility in comparison to the web.config transformation...

Comment: appsettings.{environment}.json and environment variables are only for settings that change per environment, as in Test, Staging, Production, i.e., connection strings, ws endpoints, etc. those settings will affect the apps on the entire box. I'm assuming you have multiple clients on the same box in, say, a Production environment? at that point you will either need a separate appsettings per client (per app pool) that your build or deployment process can produce, or a multi-tenant scenario which is a whole other can of worms.

Comment: This is how I understood the "new" way .netcore configuration works. I am swapping out files already during the build process, but I was looking for a similar solution as we had in place before. I still think it is a step backwards from transformations. E.g. in the build process I run int. tests against a sep. database on my dev server (same machine). For this it fails already. One could argue connection-strings should not go into the app.config, but that is not the point. It would have been nice to be able to pass a "environment parameter" on the build or similar to the build configuration...